# XSLT: unordered flat XML to hierarchy with grouping by ID's

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am struggling to create a transformation with XSLT 1.0 to present my data hierarchically by their GUID's. I have a flat XML which contains data about folders and their files, unordered. I want to present this data in a tree structure.

Flat XML unordered:

```
<tns:Response>
 <tns:Result>
  <tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:fFolderGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fFolderGUID>
     <tns:fParentGUID>F050669AEA220E5B6D32FB92ABDB0080</tns:fParentGUID>
     <tns:fFolderName>Folder 0</tns:fFolderName>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>91FEE5D69B8ABCE6DBEDE95344D962CE</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 5</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>91FEE5D69B8ABCE6DBEDE95344D962CE</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 6</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 1</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 2</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>0F2F52149628A0029C436500873A1F1F</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 3</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFolder>
        <tns:fFolderGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</tns:fFolderGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:fFolderName>Folder 4</tns:fFolderName>
     </tns:ChildFolder>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>68E2DB7C43ED0C4C14D902398AD494FC</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 4 - 1</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>15D8716AAACDAEFDCBA77434BF62649D</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 2 - 2</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>8DB55ACDC7518F0C2062456B0B467375</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 2 - 1</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>AD7476CEF93E5C2A9F69DAFE6D42066D</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 6 - 2</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>00011D503C2691173A8A2C3004E9BE4E</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 6 - 1</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>CE82CD61E4D913817C3C795F1403C621</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 0 - 1</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>65DB227672A92D4DB1F153EB5EF5D41B</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 0 - 2</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>2099C99CE0B1BE9FA5A7152F21F23330</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 1 - 1</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
     <tns:ChildFile>
        <tns:fFileGUID>32F8C5F47475A093D1AE748552AD1A21</tns:fFileGUID>
        <tns:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</tns:fParentGUID>
        <tns:dDocTitle>Document 1 - 2</tns:dDocTitle>
     </tns:ChildFile>
  </tns:ChildFolder>
```

And I would like it to be sorted in a tree strcuture, as follows:

```
<ns0:Response>
<ns0:Result>
  <ns0:ChildFolder>
     <ns0:fFolderGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fFolderGUID>
     <ns0:fParentGUID>F050669AEA220E5B6D32FB92ABDB0080</ns0:fParentGUID>
     <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 0</ns0:fFolderName>
     <ns0:ChildFile>
        <ns0:fFileGUID>CE82CD61E4D913817C3C795F1403C621</ns0:fFileGUID>
        <ns0:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fParentGUID>
        <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 0 - 1</ns0:dDocTitle>
     </ns0:ChildFile>
     <ns0:ChildFile>
        <ns0:fFileGUID>65DB227672A92D4DB1F153EB5EF5D41B</ns0:fFileGUID>
        <ns0:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fParentGUID>
        <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 0 - 2</ns0:dDocTitle>
     </ns0:ChildFile>
     <ns0:ChildFolder>
        <ns0:fFolderGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</ns0:fFolderGUID>
        <ns0:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fParentGUID>
        <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 1</ns0:fFolderName>
        <ns0:ChildFile>
           <ns0:fFileGUID>2099C99CE0B1BE9FA5A7152F21F23330</ns0:fFileGUID>
           <ns0:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</ns0:fParentGUID>
           <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 1 - 1</ns0:dDocTitle>
        </ns0:ChildFile>
        <ns0:ChildFile>
           <ns0:fFileGUID>32F8C5F47475A093D1AE748552AD1A21</ns0:fFileGUID>
           <ns0:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</ns0:fParentGUID>
           <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 1 - 2</ns0:dDocTitle>
        </ns0:ChildFile>
        <ns0:ChildFolder>
           <ns0:fFolderGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</ns0:fFolderGUID>
           <ns0:fParentGUID>99964626C187728B8A0823564126D091</ns0:fParentGUID>
           <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 4</ns0:fFolderName>
           <ns0:ChildFile>
              <ns0:fFileGUID>68E2DB7C43ED0C4C14D902398AD494FC</ns0:fFileGUID>
              <ns0:fParentGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</ns0:fParentGUID>
              <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 4 - 1</ns0:dDocTitle>
           </ns0:ChildFile>
           <ns0:ChildFolder>
              <ns0:fFolderGUID>91FEE5D69B8ABCE6DBEDE95344D962CE</ns0:fFolderGUID>
              <ns0:fParentGUID>D5F39DA59300A125437090D6E1A8BA89</ns0:fParentGUID>
              <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 5</ns0:fFolderName>
              <ns0:ChildFolder>
                 <ns0:fFolderGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</ns0:fFolderGUID>
                 <ns0:fParentGUID>91FEE5D69B8ABCE6DBEDE95344D962CE</ns0:fParentGUID>
                 <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 6</ns0:fFolderName>
                 <ns0:ChildFile>
                    <ns0:fFileGUID>AD7476CEF93E5C2A9F69DAFE6D42066D</ns0:fFileGUID>
                    <ns0:fParentGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</ns0:fParentGUID>
                    <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 6 - 2</ns0:dDocTitle>
                 </ns0:ChildFile>
                 <ns0:ChildFile>
                    <ns0:fFileGUID>00011D503C2691173A8A2C3004E9BE4E</ns0:fFileGUID>
                    <ns0:fParentGUID>13A6EB7420E7586B21CC8F9CCED8AAA5</ns0:fParentGUID>
                    <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 6 - 1</ns0:dDocTitle>
                 </ns0:ChildFile>
              </ns0:ChildFolder>
           </ns0:ChildFolder>
        </ns0:ChildFolder>
     </ns0:ChildFolder>
     <ns0:ChildFolder>
        <ns0:fFolderGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</ns0:fFolderGUID>
        <ns0:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fParentGUID>
        <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 2</ns0:fFolderName>
        <ns0:ChildFile>
           <ns0:fFileGUID>15D8716AAACDAEFDCBA77434BF62649D</ns0:fFileGUID>
           <ns0:fParentGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</ns0:fParentGUID>
           <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 2 - 2</ns0:dDocTitle>
        </ns0:ChildFile>
        <ns0:ChildFile>
           <ns0:fFileGUID>8DB55ACDC7518F0C2062456B0B467375</ns0:fFileGUID>
           <ns0:fParentGUID>FEAD438C243F2AB6D3F273D4BBE701C3</ns0:fParentGUID>
           <ns0:dDocTitle>Document 2 - 1</ns0:dDocTitle>
        </ns0:ChildFile>
     </ns0:ChildFolder>
     <ns0:ChildFolder>
        <ns0:fFolderGUID>0F2F52149628A0029C436500873A1F1F</ns0:fFolderGUID>
        <ns0:fParentGUID>F3CF39082F7CD2DC9AAD9E34D6BFDA84</ns0:fParentGUID>
        <ns0:fFolderName>Folder 3</ns0:fFolderName>
     </ns0:ChildFolder>
  </ns0:ChildFolder>
 </ns0:Result>
</ns0:Response>
```

Currently I am using for-eaches to test whether a folder/file is a child of the parent folder together with a variable that holds the position for every level. This way I can only present a limited number of levels. It must be possible to do this in an easier way. Thanks for helping out community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a key or two to follow the id references, then process/apply-templates to all referenced children:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/tns"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tns"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="child-files" match="tns:ChildFile" use="tns:fParentGUID"/>
  <xsl:key name="child-folders" match="tns:ChildFolder" use="tns:fParentGUID"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tns:ChildFolder">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:*[not(self::tns:ChildFolder | self::tns:ChildFile)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child-files', tns:fFolderGUID)"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child-folders', tns:fFolderGUID)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJt has an online sample. As keys work on the whole document this approach will not work if the ids used for the key values are not unique in the complete document and there are several folders having the same id. But as the values seem to be GUIDs I guess you have unique values.

Comment: Yes! This is indeed the solution! The code is so efficient, I never thought it would be this easy. I'll read more about using keys. Thanks so much for your help Martin :)